Edge autofill - fills all of the email inputs
I have a form with multiple email inputs.
Edge fills all of them at once with the same value.
I would prefer if Edge would only fill that one field, on which action is being performed.
I've tried different tricks with labels, names, placeholders etc..
I do not want to disable autocomplete entirely.
Edit.
Detecting changes in inputs and then, filtering out duplicates is unfortunately not an option.

I can reproduce the issue and I don't find any solution, unless you disable autofill for the inputs. I suggest that you can provide feedback to Edge team by pressing Alt+Shift+I in Edge. Thanks for your understanding!
